# How to construct an equation with single input variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to set up this equation - h = (GMT^2/4π^2)1/3 −R - where 'h' is the height of an orbiting satellite, G is the gravitational constant, M is the earth's mass and R is the earth's radius. For a user given value of 'T' the program must return the height (h) required to allow an orbit period of the user's 'T'

So far I've attempted to write the equation, subsequently defining the constants that are relevant.

```
h=[math.pow(((G*M*math.pow(T,2))/(4*math.pow(Pi,2))),1/3)-R]

G=6.67*math.pow(10,-11)
M=5.97*math.pow(10,24)
R=6371
T=input('Period of Orbit (T)=',)

print(h)
```

Upon hovering over the warning triangle next to the top line the error message "Undefined Name ..." appears, which proceeds to list G, M, T, Pi and R as all undefined. This error is reiterated in the kernel when trying to run the program. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You use those variables before defining them. Put your first line of code after you define all the variables (i.e. right before the `print` statement).

Comment: You'll also need to convert the string you get from input into a number. You can also use `math.pi`

Comment: If you want to change the input variable, you should be defining a function.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're calculating `h` in a list.

Comment: Please return to your class materials and work through the components of programming.  You have missed several critical concepts.  Also, write only one or two statements at a time; do not continue until they do what you expect.  Part of your problem is that you've made several errors before attempting execution; this leaves you having to fix several problems simultaneously to get reasonable results.

Comment: `h` isn't a function.  It's just a variable that you're assigning a single-element list to (not sure why it's a list).  So it gets evaluated on the spot.  Since `G`, `M`, `R`, and `T` are not defined at that point, you get an error.  It might make more sense to define it as a function, with `G`, `M`, `R`, and `T` as parameters.  That way you could change their values and simply pass them to the function to get the new result.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm guessing right about what you want, it should be something like:

```py
from math import pow, pi

R = 6371  # earth's radius
G = 6.67 * pow(10, -11)  # gravitational constant
M = 5.97 * pow(10, 24)  # earth's mass

# desired period
T = int(input('Period of Orbit (T)=',))

h = pow((G * M * pow(T,2)) / (4 * pow(pi,2)), 1/3) - R
print(f"Height needed: {h}")
```

I've also added in more whitespace for readability. I'd second the recommendation to define a function, which would look more like:

```
from math import pow, pi

def calculate_orbit_height(period):
    R = 6371  # earth's radius
    G = 6.67 * pow(10, -11)  # gravitational constant
    M = 5.97 * pow(10, 24)  # earth's mass
    return pow((G * M * pow(period,2)) / (4 * pow(pi,2)), 1/3) - R

# desired period
T = int(input('Period of Orbit (T)=',))
print(f"Height needed: {calculate_orbit_height(T)}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, worked perfectly, as you can probably tell I'm relatively new to coding, I'm a physics student so my knowledge mostly revolves around graphing and numerical analysis, would you perhaps be able to explain some of the jargon in the comments and what the 'def' and the 'f' after print actually represent??

Comment: The keyword "def" means "I'm about to define a function"- you can learn a lot about this (and other Python language features, such as f-strings) from the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: Also, if my (or someone else's) answer solved your problem, you probably want to [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score -2):

A few things so far that I've noticed:

1. Import math
2. Declare your variables before using them
3. T is a string, so in your equation use int(T)
4. Try using math.pi

It should work after that.[Working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhU8m.png)

edit: as Fred pointed out, the equation doesn't need to be in a list.